# Mocking partials with Jest doesn't work for a functional expression exported along with a React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my React app I have a component called Chart, where I also have a functional expression exported. It put there as it's uniquely used with that particular component.

```
export const setSecurity = (securityCode: string) => {
     console.log("securityCode:", securityCode);
    // set Security code
};
const Chart = () => {
    const { selectedValue } = useContext(SelectedValueContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("selectedValue changed", selectedValue);
        if (selectedValue) {
            setSecurity(selectedValue);
        }
    }, [selectedValue]);
   // the rest of the Chart component code
});

export default Chart;
```

Given that, I want to test if the value correctly passed through the useContext hook. To do so, I want to mock the setSecurity function and check if it's being called and with what parameters:

```
// other import statements
import Chart, { setSecurity } from "./Chart";

jest.mock("./Chart", () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual("./Chart");

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        setSecurity: jest.fn(),
    };
});

describe("Chart", ()=>{

  it("should pass the value it get from the context provider", async () => {
        const providerValue = {
            selectedValue: "Test",
        };
        render(
            <SelectedValueContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
                <Chart />
            </SelectedValueContext.Provider>,
        );

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByTestId("chartiq")).toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        expect(setSecurity).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(setSecurity).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test");
    });

});
```

When I run my test, I am able to see both console.log in the terminal with the correct selectedValue value, however the test fails on the first expect stating the setSecurity has been called 0 times not 1.

I was able to fix that by moving setSecurity function to a separate file and removing it from the Chart file, but just curious if there's any explanation why the partial mock doesn't work or where is an error.
Would appreciate much if anyone can explain, also would like to get a feedback on what's the best practice in such a case.